# Switching between columns in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a folder with a lot of csv files, I want move column A to C, leave column A empty and push all other columns to the right.
I tried looking for something similar, but all other examples I saw refer to specific csv files and not an iteration over a folder.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here, the code to iterate over csvfile on your folder. Fill ellipsis with your code:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

root_dir = pathlib.Path('your_directory_path_here')

for csvfile in root_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, ...)  # read your csv
    # modify the order of your column here
    ...
    shutil.copyfile(csvfile, f"{csvfile}.bak") # backup your csv
    df.to_csv(csvfile, ...) # write back your dataframe
```

Comment: @OmerDavidi. Is it what you expect?

Comment: it's a start... i can;t enter the csv filenames manually thought, the name is generated by a machine and it would be to hard to make a list of them (and there are lot...)

Comment: Without [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to help you more.